# Android FirebaseML - Local model is not registered:

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

Hi I'm building an app for a personal project, What I want to do is to use a model (.tflite) hosted in Firebase MLKit on my android app.

Whenever I want to consult my model I call a function that contains the following code:

```java
FirebaseModelDownloadConditions.Builder conditionsBuilder = new FirebaseModelDownloadConditions.Builder().requireWifi();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
      conditionsBuilder = conditionsBuilder
             .requireCharging()
             .requireDeviceIdle();
}

FirebaseModelDownloadConditions conditions = conditionsBuilder.build();

FirebaseRemoteModel cloudSource = new FirebaseRemoteModel.Builder("places-recommend")
        .enableModelUpdates(true)
        .setInitialDownloadConditions(conditions)
        .setUpdatesDownloadConditions(conditions)
        .build();

FirebaseModelManager.getInstance().registerRemoteModel(cloudSource);

FirebaseModelOptions options = new FirebaseModelOptions.Builder()
        .setRemoteModelName("places-recommend")
        .setLocalModelName("places-recommend")
        .build();

FirebaseModelInterpreter firebaseInterpreter = FirebaseModelInterpreter.getInstance(options);

FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions inputOutputOptions =
        new FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions.Builder()
                .setInputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, new int[]{1, 3})
                .setOutputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, new int[]{1, 34})
                .build();
```

However the interpreter line:

```java
FirebaseModelInterpreter firebaseInterpreter = FirebaseModelInterpreter.getInstance(options);
```

throws a FirebaseMLException:

```
Local model is not registered: places-recommend
```

Im following the Firebase guide, but i havent found a solution yet, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seemed to have registered the remote model but not the local one. When you declare your model `options` you are trying to `setLocalModelName` but the model hasn't been registered. Add the following line right before you set the `options` variable:

`FirebaseModelManager.getInstance().registerLocalModel(localSource);`

Alternatively, if you don't need to use a local model and only want to use the one you have published via the Firebase console, you can remove the following line:
`.setLocalModelName("places-recommend")`

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed how i solved the issue, i had forgoten to register the local model.